# How to correct unwanted mschart splines?

Tags: c#, charts, mschart, spline

I'm writing C# code for calculating something and plotting them via mschart. 
But my data looks like image i added below. My spline data is 1,2,3,4 for y axis,
and 5000,8000,10000,11000 for x axis. There is a bold closed spline around my spline.
How can i fix this?

[image: unwanted spline chart]

My code is:

```
var lines = new Series("lines");
lines.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(5000, 1);
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(8000, 2);
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(10000, 3);
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(11000, 4);
```

Comment: You are talking about two different series here. Makes no sense.

Answer (score -1):

I could't add second image to my question, so i used answer link.

If i add data to chart from properties menu and make IsEmpty option True, chart displays correctly. But i should do it via code. I searched for code and i found

```
public bool IsEmpty { get; set; }
```

But it didn't work.
Here is the correct chart image:

[image: correct chart]

I couldn't fix it via code.